# Why Facebook like and send button is not getting the correct url - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

in my website http://youmark.it/ I have in the home page post and in all other single post pages the same number of like, also the send button once you click is showing the Facebook Page url and not the Post url.

I have integrated all stuff for open graph, if you look at the source code it seems to be ok but still doesn't work after few changes I did. Also in the Facebook Debug tool everything shows correct.

Does Facebook need time to get updated or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have all your like buttons “pointing” to the base URL of your website.

If you want them to like the individual article, then include the URL to that article in the `href` parameter of the `<fb:like>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to like this url: `<?php the_permalink() ?>` instead?

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink() ?>&amp;send=...
```

???